# Force to update cell in DataGridView after BingingSource has changed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource

I have an array of objects. Each object has some properties and I am updating these properties periodically. In my form I have a DataGridView where row is an object from array and columns are their properties. I want to see changes in objects immediately in DataGridView so I used BindingSource:

```
Dim _myArray(10) As MyObject
Dim bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource()

bs.DataSource = _myArray
myGrid.DataSource = bs
```

If I am changing some property in object I am doing it via BindingSource (not directly in array):

```
DirectCast(bs(index), MyObject).Property1 = newValue
```

All this works but I have to call `UpdateCellValue(columnIndex, rowIndex)` to take affect this new value in dataGridView (value is there but I have to update this cell to show new value in UI).

As I said I am changing properties periodically in 1 second interval so values are changing often. How can I do that without calling `UpdateCellValue`?

There is a BindingSource with datasource so I expect to see changed values immediately after change. If I have to call `UpdateCellValue` I don't need BindingSource! Instead of BindingSource I can fire some event PropertyChanged in object and in method which handles this event I can update cell!

I know I can "reattach" datasource of DataGridView to reload data with changed values but this is stupid if I am doing changes in 1 second interval. Thank you.

Comment: The best way to make sure that the changes are performed immediately and accurately in the DGV is modifying the DGV directly. I, personally, prefer to not edit the DataSources because there might be some "coordination problems".

Comment: So what is a purpose of BindingSource in this case? Behaving is like without BindingSource (only set DataSource of DGW to array).

Comment: The purpose of any binding is setting a relationship between the data and the given control; but by bearing in mind that both remain different realities and thus any change in one of them is not immediate in the other one (although would eventually happen). As far as, usually the part triggering errors (at least when DGV is involved) is the control (because the application is constantly checking it), out of the two options you have (editing the DataSource or the Control directly), I choose the control. On top of that you are complaining about the update of the control being too slow...

Comment: ... presumably because of having a pretty big dataset; so what you expect? Graphical example (describing basically the same): What is quicker the transfer of files by an internet connection between two computers 10000km away one from the other; or within the local harddrive?

Comment: My dataset has 12 rows and 5 columns so it is pretty small. My point is that it doesn't seem to be an ideal solution to update cells manualy when my data are binded. I just thought that if I load some data and save them to my objects why should I save them also into DGV if it is binded (it would be better to do that automatically). I am reading data each second but values are not changing all the time. And if only one value has changed, I don't want to reload whole table because of it.

Comment: In theory, if you set a .DataSource = DataTable and the size is not too relevant; any change you perform in the DataTable is, almost, immediately reflected in the DGV without doing any else. BUT there are many circumstances which might required the DGV to be refreshed, that might make that the given event (every time you modified anything on the DGV, quite a few events are triggered automatically) finds a problem, etc. Bear in mind that you have a communication between two different objects which might be affected by many factors. That's why my recommendation: focus on what is more...

Comment: ... important for you: the DGV. If the DataSource is updated 1sec later it wouldn't really matter. This is my general recommendation; the only kind of answer you should expect for a so generic question. If you want a specific solution for a specific problem, you should ask a specific question by providing the specific conditions (e.g., code).